# My customized bootstrap Navbar won't stay fixed

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've created a bootstrap navbar then I changed the color, background-color and hover color. The problem is that eversince I made these changes, the navbar won't stay fixed. I am new to CSS and I searched everywhere for a solution, sadly everywhere I look says to swap the navbar-static to navbar-fixed, but I already have navbar-fixed in my code. Please help!

Here is the relevant CSS and HTML:

```css
.navbar-custom {
 z-index:999999;  /* here I fixed an issue where the collapsed navbar showed up underneath the slider under it*/
 position: absolute; 
 background-color: #E46142;
} 

.section1 .navbar-custom .container #navbar-collapse .nav.navbar-nav li a{
 color: white; /* Here I had to target the text very specifically otherwise the color would not change */
}

.section1 .navbar-custom .container .navbar-header .navbar-brand{
  color: white;
}

.section1 .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top .container .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
 background-color: white;
}

ul.nav a:hover { color: #000 !important; }
```

```html
<div class="section1">
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Name</a>
        </div><!-- End Nav Bar Header -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="#">Text1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Container -->
</nav>
<!-- End Nav Bar -->
</div>
```

Comment: This might help you https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/454/

Answer (score 1):

change  `position` or remove this `position`

```
.navbar-custom {
    z-index:999999;  /* here I fixed an issue where the collapsed navbar showed up underneath the slider under it*/
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: #E46142;
}
```